# How to store in-game currency in iOS

Tags: ios, core-data, nsuserdefaults

I am creating an iOS app with in-game currency. What is the best way to store the in-game currency? I am looking for something that jailbreakers can't access/change, something persistent, and something fast.

I have looked into Core Data, as well as perhaps NSUserDefaults. Can anybody suggest the best method?

Comment: Store it in the keychain

Comment: It is not just about storing. Have you solve the problem of how the communication should be done? Since the traffic can be eavesdropped.

Comment: @Radu: You have to send the state back to the user for display and local calculation. Fully on server will make the game laggy if the connection is not stable. HTTPS doesn't help, since you can eavesdrop on higher level (some people have read data from https connection in DragonVale).

Comment: Definitely use NSUserDefaults, so hackers like me can get infinite coins :P. But seriously, there is no way to stop hacking on a platform like iOS. There are too many people who have jailbreaks, and while the keychain is the best option, it isn't infallible, hackers can still access it if they are determined.

Comment: Can I store it in SQLite through Core Data? Is there any problem with that? The Core Data Programming Guide says it's secure...

Comment: In the past, when doing something similar, I created a plist and stored it there. How secure/useful is that? Advantages/Disadvantages?

Comment: @LennyK: On a jailbroken system, it is like inviting people to have a look.

Comment: Ok, so not doing that :)

Comment: About the best that you can do is to store it in the keychain.  It isn't infallible, but it is the best there is and will make it difficult to access.  You can always encrypt the string but eventually it will have to be unencrypted to display it and when you modify it so it really doesn't make it that much more secure for people hacking away....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to follow iTukker's recommendation above and store them in the keychain.

But I wanted to add some additional info:

Anything that you store or calculate locally (meaning in the device) could theoretically be tampered with.  No solution can offer you the level of security that calculating and storing those values server-side would.  And even then, there's always the chance to fool the server into giving you more rewards through other means.

What I mean to say is that you have to look for something that's "good enough" rather than completely secure.  What "good enough" is, depends on you.